# Typescript ошибка типов UnwrapRefSimple

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vue-cli

У меня есть тип UserServicesResponse[]. В нем мне приходят данные с бэка, с этим же типом объявлена переменная, в которую я записываю этот ответ. Казалось бы, одинаковый тип, что может пойти не так? Однако, получаю вот такую ошибку

Assigned expression type UserServicesResponse[] is not assignable to type Array<UnwrapRefSimple>

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Проект сделан на vue3 + typsscript + vite + pinia